How to pass the current request id to ActiveJob and ActionMailer for tagged logging?
I want to improve the logging of my application. I use tagged logging with the request_id. Basically this is rails standard for production environments.
I'd like to know from where log lines from sidekiq, actionmailer and activejob origin from.
I use Rails Semantic Logger to get structured logs.
For sidekiq, I found to use job tags which are being picked up by rails semantic logger and are now being logged which help to identify log lines which belong together.
This looks something as follows
21:15:30 worker.1    | 2024-10-22 21:15:30.273383 I [71200:sidekiq.default/processor] {jid: 32abadde984a6b6c5a95e1ed, tags: ["my-request-id"], queue: default} (44.6ms) AppointmentCompletionMissingReminderJob -- Completed #perform

This is probably not the best solution but at least it does the job.
Now I want to have the request id in logs created by actionmailer and activejob as well. One could isolate the problem to activejob with the assumption of using a custom deliveryjob and not the default ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob.
Currently I have logs as follows:
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.433809 I [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] Rails -- Performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: 3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1) to Async(high) -- { :event_name => "perform_start.active_job", :adapter => "Async", :queue => "high", :job_class => "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob", :job_id => "3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1", :provider_job_id => "fcab8cb1-e661-4821-916a-695e5e42e70f", :arguments => "[\n  \"UserMailer\",\n  \"magic_link\",\n  \"deliver_now\",\n  {\n    \"params\": {\n      \"user\": \"gid://xxx/User/1\",\n      \"redirect_path\": \"\"\n    },\n    \"args\": [\n\n    ]\n  }\n]" }
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.434135 D [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] UserMailer -- Sending magic link to user
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.446786 D [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] ActionView -- Rendering layout -- { :template => "layouts/mailer.haml" }
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.446812 D [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] ActionView -- Rendering -- { :template => "user_mailer/magic_link.html.erb" }
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.470154 D [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] (23.3ms) ActionView -- Rendered -- { :template => "user_mailer/magic_link.html.erb", :within => "layouts/mailer", :allocations => 33255 }
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.472222 I [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] ActionMailer::Base -- UserMailer#magic_link: processed outbound mail in 38.1ms -- { :event_name => "process.action_mailer", :mailer => "UserMailer", :action => :magic_link, :message_id => nil, :perform_deliveries => nil, :subject => nil, :to => nil, :from => nil, :bcc => nil, :cc => nil, :date => nil, :args => nil }

where 3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1 is the job id created by activejob. I'd like to have another log tag containing the request id.
I use ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes to provide it with Current.request_id everywhere in my application.
The question is, how can I inject the request id to the job when it gets created, e.g. in my sign-in controller?
The result should be something like this:
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.433809 I [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] [my-request-id] Rails ...
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.434135 D [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] [my-request-id] UserMailer ...
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.446786 D [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] [my-request-id] ActionView ...
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.446812 D [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] [my-request-id] ActionView ...
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.470154 D [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] [my-request-id] (23.3ms) ActionView ...
21:06:52 web.1       | 2024-10-22 21:06:52.472222 I [71197:worker-1] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [3821d8b0-d6fe-4f12-8e6a-a5c3d152d2e1] [my-request-id] ActionMailer::Base ...


Rails provides the RequestId middleware, which automatically assigns a unique request ID to every request. This can be accessed via request.request_id in controllers, but you need to explicitly pass it to background jobs for logging.
Here’s how you can do that:
a. Pass request ID to ActiveJob:
You can pass the request ID as part of the job's arguments:
class SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args, request_id)
    # Add the request_id to the logs using tagged logging
    Rails.logger.tagged("RequestId: #{request_id}") do
      # Your job code here
    end
  end
end


Get rid of the two completly reduntant sentances and this is a decent answer.

Thank you. Sure I can pass another parameter. This helps for log messages I manually create within the job. It does not help for logs created by the framework itself. E.g. lines including "Performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob". Another tricky part is injecting the request id to the action mailer framework to get it passed to ActiveJob. I hope my goal is clear?
